# perl Configure VC-WIN32 --perfix=E:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl\Release

Tags: c#, perl, visual-studio-2015, telegram

First of all the tools I've installed are:

1) Windows 10 Pro Enterprise Version 10.0.10240 Build 10240

2) Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

3) Windows SDK 10

4) strawberry perl 5.22.1.3

Recently I tried to create a telegram project using Telegram APIs. After some googling I download the source from [github](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop) and followed the [Build instructions for Visual Studio 2015](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/doc/building-msvc.md). 
The three first commands executed successfully but not the forth one and the below error occurs:
The command I mentioned is:

> perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl\Release

The error:

> 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I found that, the Release Folder does not exists. My first question is that do I need to build the openssl project first? If yes so how? Do I need to install extra tools for that command?

Second question is do I need to install anything for other instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is issued by your command interpreter because it cannot find the Perl executable. Locate the perl.exe from your Strawberry Perl distribution and specify a full path to it, e.g. `"c:\Program Files\strawberry\bin\perl.exe" Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl\Release`. Note that your exact path is likely to differ from my sample; I haven't checked where Strawberry drops its files.

Comment: Is it enouph to copy the perl.exe to "D:\TBuild\Libraries\openssl" directory?

Comment: Maybe, but probably not. The installer ensures that things are set up so they'll work. It probably makes no guarantees that things will keep working when you copy a single file elsewhere.